# How to remove key from nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have a nested dictionary like:

[{'rule': {'actions': {'allow': False}, 'dl_type': 2048, 'ipv4_dst': '192.168.50.0/24', 'ipv4_src': '192.168.50.20'}}, **{'rule': {'actions': {'allow': False}, 'dl_type': 2048, 'ipv4_dst': '192.168.50.0/24', 'ipv4_src': '192.168.50.10'}}**, {'rule': {'actions': {'allow': True}}}]

I want to remove this from my nested dictionary:

{'rule': {'actions': {'allow': False}, 'dl_type': 2048, 'ipv4_dst': '192.168.50.0/24', 'ipv4_src': '192.168.50.10'}}

How would I do something like this? I don't think I can remove the dictionary based on the key because it looks like there are multiple dictionaries that contain the same keys. It sounds like it should be simple, but I can't seem to remove that dictionary and the nested dictionaries inside of it (maybe because I'm burned out for the day). Any help is greatly appreciated on this!

Comment: The data you provide is  a _list_ of dictionaries.  The nested dictionary is `actions` under `rule`.  What has `yaml` to do with it?

Comment: @DanielFarrell They are generated from a YAML file using the YAML module in Py3, but maybe I should've excluded it.

Comment: Use the list's `remove` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the difference between the bolded element and the previous element is the value for `ipv4_src` i.e., `192.168.50.10`, therefore you could use a **[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)** to remove the dictionary with that:

```
org_list = [{
    'rule': {
        'actions': {
            'allow': False
        },
        'dl_type': 2048,
        'ipv4_dst': '192.168.50.0/24',
        'ipv4_src': '192.168.50.20'
    }
}, {
    'rule': {
        'actions': {
            'allow': False
        },
        'dl_type': 2048,
        'ipv4_dst': '192.168.50.0/24',
        'ipv4_src': '192.168.50.10'  # this is the difference
    }
}, {
    'rule': {
        'actions': {
            'allow': True
        }
    }
}]

new_list = [
    d for d in org_list if d['rule'].get('ipv4_src', '') != '192.168.50.10'
]

print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'rule': {'actions': {'allow': False}, 'dl_type': 2048, 'ipv4_dst': '192.168.50.0/24', 'ipv4_src': '192.168.50.20'}}, {'rule': {'actions': {'allow': True}}}]
```